# How to get indexPath of UICollectionViewCell based on cell text?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I pass the cell title label from "collection view A" to "collection view B". So now in collection View B, I have the cell's title label.

In the viewDidAppear method for collection View B, I'd like to use scrollToItemAtIndexPath to scroll to the proper index containing the cell with that title label.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Collections work like TableViews.  Most people have a backing store of data behind their collection or tableview, which is an array with data in the proper order.  Thus, when your cellForRowAtIndexPath or cellForItemAtIndexPath call is invoked, you simply stuff in the value from your backing store.  If your model is the same as this you would simply search your collection view B backing store array for the label, and make note of what row it is in.

Comment: This searching in the array and the rest of the logic would take place in cellForItemAtIndexPath instead of viewdidAppear?

Comment: You have two collections.  You have a way of determining what gets put in each cell based on the index path the system calls for.  This method is invoked by cellForItemAtIndexPath.  Maybe it's an array, maybe it's a dynamic function. When you need to find out where in B your mystery label is, simply  invoke the same process that cellForItemAtIndexPath does when it gets an index path.

Comment: Then invoke that process for all the rows until you find your title.